# AND operation in C#

Tags: c#

I want to perform an `AND` operation. My inputs are 2 objects. It could be a string like "true" or it could be an expression like "1==1" as well. When using `&&` operator, am getting an exception that String was not recognized as a valid `boolean`.

Please help me.

```
return Convert.ToBoolean(obj[0]) && Convert.ToBoolean(obj[1]);
```

Sorry for the earlier post which was not clear enough.

Comment: Try `return Convert.ToBoolean("true") && Convert.ToBoolean(1==1);` (note the lack of quotes around 1==1).

Comment: Try: return Convert.ToBoolean("true") && (1==1);

Comment: `true` is already a boolean, and `1==1` is already a boolean, what is the conversion supposed to do?

Comment: Do you really have the inputs as string? Why?

Comment: @VaibhavDesai - His problem is that "1==1" probably is user input, and therefore a string. If not, then why bother with Convert.ToBoolean at all and just write `return true && 1==1;`, or even simpler `return true;`

Comment: @Sayse - The string "true" and the string "1==1" is not booleans however, and will have to be converted if he actually have these as string representations (for example user inputs)

Comment: Don't ask any useless question

Comment: @ØyvindKnobloch-Bråthen I don't know. People do weird stuff all the time. When I recently switched to Java, I wrote System.out.println(e.printStackTrace()). My colleagues laughed over it :)

Comment: Do you have a discrete set of strings that you can get??

Comment: @VaibhavDesai - Yes, you do strange things when new to a language ;). But now after the edit, it seems that he has managed to express his problem a bit better, and there should be no doubt ;)

Comment: Why can't you ensure that inputs are translated to Boolean before you process them? Perhaps have a list of 'true' inputs and a list of 'false' inputs. Everything else is invalid. Do TrueList.Contains(input) to evaluate to boolean after checking input validity.

Comment: the question was edited in a way, that renders all current answers ridiculous

Comment: @Matus - Not mine I hope.

Comment: @Gusdor - A list of **all** possible true or false inputs? So true list would include "1==1","2==2",....,"999999==999999",......,"99999999999==99999999999",... and false list "1==2","1==3,"1==4",...? That does not seem like a very feasible solution. I think parsing the string into an expression is the only logical approach here, if you don't know for sure that the input set is very limited, and you don't have to be able to parse arbitrary strings.

Comment: @ØyvindKnobloch-Bråthen - no, not yours

Comment: @ØyvindKnobloch-Bråthen I was trying to impress that where text input is given, you need to establish a collection of tests that will evaluate or reject input. My comment laid out a simple example, hoping that the OP could extrapolate from there - this is a design issue and I'm not doing his homework. For this case I would recommended using a regex to validate and parse the expressions. Perhaps a list of input parsers would work better, where each parser returns a Nullable<bool> and the first non-null value from the list is used...

Answer (score 3):

Converting `"1==1"` to a `boolean` is not possible for the `Convert.ToBoolean` method. It just converts the strings `true` and `false`.

You will have to either write a expression evaluator yourself, or use some kind of library to parse your string to a boolean (like [Flee](http://flee.codeplex.com/) for example)

Comment: This is true for Convert.ToBoolean(string); there are other overloads for Convert.ToBoolean.  Convert.ToBoolean(1==1) will return true as well.

Comment: Then what should I use?

Comment: See my edit. When the expression is a string, it's not elementary to solve it anymore. How will you parse any string to a boolean? You can  make your own easy one if you only need to support "X==Y" constructs, but if you want to support more advanced input I would use a library.

Answer (score 1):

First make sure obj[0], obj[1] will only contain 1 or 0(char or integer).
Because Convert.ToBoolean does not understand anything other than 1 or 0.

Answer (score 0):

The below one will work

```
Convert.ToBoolean(true) && Convert.ToBoolean(1==1)
```

Comment: or `true && (1==1)`, or simply `true`

Answer (score 0):

Why use a string?
The conversion will not evaluate code, it will check if the supplied data is possible to convert to a bool and do so if possible.

Your function will always return true if it was working, cause 1 is always equal to 1, and true is always true.

Answer (score -1):

This is nearly impossible as C# is strongly type language.
 What you trying to do is for weakly types languages like JS. `"1==1"` will work for JS, not for C#.
 Remove quotes in order to make it work(You might as well remove first operand, as it doesn't make any sense):

```
return ( 1 == 1 );
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood his question.

Comment: @user1671639: I don't think so.

Comment: @BartFriederichs, indeed. I just wanted to leave at least numbers )

Comment: "nearly impossible". Nothing is impossible in software - the only constraint is time.